# MySQL Scale Issue - Triggers / Updating / Monitoring Tables

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, triggers

- We run a high transaction volume insurance system.
- The goal is to update a single flat table of 200 columns on any changes in a customers profile.
- The customers profile is stored in a complex model of around 400 tables.
- e.g If the customer makes a single premium payment, it goes across 15+ tables but we want the flat table to update say 5 out of 200 columns to reflect some representative data off this payment for the customer
- We are considering using triggers, that is not working out well in testing as the current MySQL server (AWS Aurora) is not able to deal with it.
- The main application is PHP Code-igniter

Any one has any suggestions that can help?

Comment: `around 400 tables` what? you crazy.  And here I thought 25 tables was bad, we have around 6 DB though with different things.   Sorry it's just that seems excessive.

Comment: Any one of his bullet points is enough to nut me out.

Answer (score 0):

"If the customer makes a single premium payment ..." --

That should touch about 2 tables.

- A record of the payment (who, when, how much; not much more)
- Some kind of status for the user.

The first of those tables is a running "log" of what happened.  The second is the current state of things.

Having 400 tables or 200 columns, or touching 15 tables for a simple operation -- each of these indicate poor design.

It is OK, even normal, to have a few (not 400) `JOINs` to reconstruct things on the `SELECT` side.